# Is there a connection between wans't/wanst and wasn't?

Tags: etymology, archaicisms

Wasn't is the contracted form of *was not*.
But wanst/wans't was an archaic adverb meaning **once**:

> *"Be the bye, I **wanst** knew art ould woman of that name. She was my darling Tibbie, but a notorious drunkard"*. <sup>1</sup>
>
> *"Now, shut your eyes, and turn round **wanst**" whispered the Grey Man. Shawn did as he was desired; but, when he looked about, he was struck all of a hape to find himself standing in his own bawn....* <sup>2</sup>

<sup>1</sup> 1863, Roger Quinn, The Heather Lintie: [*Being Poetical Pieces, Spiritual and Temporal...*‎](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=NmoNAAAAYAAJ&pg=PA167&dq=wanst&lr=&as_brr=1&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=wanst&f=false), page 167

<sup>2</sup> 1838, Charles Dickens et al, [*Bentley's Miscellany‎*](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=E7kRAAAAYAAJ&pg=PA308&dq=wanst&lr=&as_brr=1&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=wanst&f=false), page 308

---

NB: I originally came across the contraction *wans't* (sic) [here](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/449917/is-this-grammar-right-for-asking), which led me to *wanst*. So I'm wondering if there is any connection between wanst or wasn't or even *wans't*.

For example, sha'n't was the dated spelling of shan't, but shalln't is the archaic form of shan't. Are there cases where the apostrophe was missed out but was intended to mean "shall not"? (shant and shallnt)

---

Instances where *wans't* is used in place of *wasn't* (though this is rare):

## The Missouri Yearbook of Agriculture ...: Annual Report ..., Volume 32 (1900)

[image]

https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=ZKlJAAAAMAAJ&q=%22wans%27t%22&dq=%22wans%27t%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiqvpndr8zbAhUNmrQKHXwrArQ4jAEQ6AEIUjAJ

## Proceedings of All Ohio Safety Congress, Volume 11 - F.J. Heer Print. Company, 1940

[image]

https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=c8k2AQAAIAAJ&q=%22wans%27t%22&dq=%22wans%27t%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjZsu7FrszbAhXSL1AKHcBMBqM4bhDoAQhOMAk

## New Times International, Issues 26-39; New Times Publishing House, 1991

[image]

https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=WmQpAQAAMAAJ&dq=It+wans%27t+for+nothing+that+Nikolai+Leskov+wrote%3A&focus=searchwithinvolume&q=wans%27t+

## Even, The Washington Post (1984)

[image]

https://www.washingtonpost.com/archive/opinions/1984/06/10/history-was-on-gary-harts-side-but-that-wanst-enough/5c74923d-67e6-491a-94bf-14ac664bdb60/?noredirect=on&utm_term=.379ce6a0edc2

---

## Wans't (or rather wanst) as eye dialect from the *Domestic Engineering and the Journal of Mechanical Contracting* (Volume 84, 1918)

[image]

https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=1armAAAAMAAJ&q=%22wans%27t%22&dq=%22wans%27t%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjawsapt8zbAhWIYVAKHeBmA4w4FBDoAQgmMAA

Comment: Looks like an 'olde' spelling of "once".

Comment: Under their entry for ***once***, the full OED say *The regional forms with **-st** follow the pattern seen in, e.g. **against***. It's nothing to do with contracted ***wasn't***.

Comment: Looks like "eye dialect spelling" to me https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eye_dialect but interesting discovery nonetheless.

Comment: I see. I have found *wanst* is also a [Middle High German](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Middle_High_German) word. Was it normal to use them in the Late Modern English period (1800s-)?

Comment: NHG _Wanst_, MHG _wanst_, OHG _wanast_, orig. abdominal fat deposits on an animal, transferred to humans. Basically, in middle and northern Germany, a beer gut, Austrobavarian _Wampe_. https://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/Wanst

Comment: Some of these examples appear to be typesetting errors.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*Wanst* is the 19th– early 20th c. phonetic rendering, i.e., “[eye dialect](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eye_dialect),” of the Irish pronunciation of the dialect form ‘once + [non-etymological t](https://www.etymonline.com/word/amidst)’ as in such words as *amidst, against, whilst,* and *betwixt*. In other dialects, it might be rendered as [*oncet*](https://en.m.wiktionary.org/wiki/oncet), such as [Pennsylvania Dutch](https://books.google.de/books?id=ZfscAAAAMAAJ&q=%22oncet%22&dq=%22oncet%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwji4tvxkczbAhXQxaYKHfo7D_wQ6AEISTAI) or [Appalachian](https://books.google.de/books?id=-4N6AAAAIAAJ&q=twicet&dq=twicet&hl=de&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjxhYH6k8zbAhUhDZoKHZ-uAUIQ6AEIQDAF) speech. The phonetic spelling reflects a more fronted vowel perceived as characteristic of an Irish accent.  There is a similar construction: [*twicet*](https://en.m.wiktionary.org/wiki/twicet).

> … but, Sir, is not [*wanst*](https://books.google.de/books?id=JsEsAAAAYAAJ&pg=PA190&dq=%22wanst%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjPnf7RiszbAhURiaYKHdSLBp84FBDoAQg-MAU) nought, nothin ; now, masther, sure there can't be less than nothin." Very good, Sir." " If *wanst* nought be nothin', then twicet nought must be somethin', for its double what *wanst* nought is ... — William Carleton, *Traits and Stories of the Irish Peasantry*,  vol. 2, 1830, 190.
>
> … “however the thoughts of the throuble of my poor mother made me hasten my way to Kerry, to the coast near Ventry, where my father's frinds [*wanst*](https://books.google.de/books?id=Kng4AQAAMAAJ&q=%22wanst%22&dq=%22wanst%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwi02pbRjMzbAhXP0aYKHdcLBp0Q6AEITjAJ) lived; but she had died there broken-hearted. — *The Dublin Penny Journal*,  3 (1834), 198.
>
> Faith, if I led the Tyrone in rethreat [*wanst*](https://books.google.de/books?id=JPtaAAAAMAAJ&q=%22wanst%22&dq=%22wanst%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwioqeugjszbAhXPxaYKHffAB44Q6AEISTAI) I led thim forty times! Love-o’-Women wud stay pottin' an' pottin’ from behind a rock, and wait till the fire was heaviest, an’ thin stand up an’ fire man-height clear. — Rudyard Kipling,  *Works* [Seven Seas Ed.] vol. 9, 1914, 250.

And in this anecdote from a 1918 number of [*Everybody's Magazine*](https://books.google.de/books?id=PW9IAAAAYAAJ&pg=RA4-PA58&dq=%22wanst%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwibxYuCj8zbAhXB2CwKHRFzD084FBDoAQhAMAU):

[image]

Comment: I have found an odd usage of the wons't though  from a famous Scottish journalist https://twitter.com/bbclaurak/status/950448640308449281. Shall I assume this is a typo? (Because I don't think it is referring to once) Also [here](https://www.thestar.co.uk/news/i-wans-t-the-only-one-gagged-1-315651)

Comment: @aesking Yes, that’s a typo. It’s supposed to say _wasn’t_.

Comment: Also @Janus in Scared Affair By W.L. Allen: https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=cHC7kIqBhSUC&pg=SL1-PA71&lpg=SL1-PA71&dq=wans%27t&source=bl&ots=shlbffRpoT&sig=m3-2rPJQg0Ghjx-gCVGo-Ix7zOI&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjBtJCTqczbAhWCZFAKHVqsA6w4ChDoAQhKMAk#v=onepage&q=wans't&f=false; "I wans't afraid of him taking Candy"

Comment: **Probably is a typo, in the book 36 hits for wasn't and only 1 hit for wans't.